# Modular Equivalence

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory

Given two numbers \$x,y > 2, x≠y \$  output all integers \$m\$ such that
$$
x + y \equiv x \cdot y \pmod m
$$
$$
x \cdot y > m > 2
$$

### Input

Two integers

### Output

A list of integers

### Test cases

```
3, 4 -> 5
5, 8 -> 3, 9, 27
29, 9 -> 223
26, 4 -> 37, 74
13, 11 -> 7, 17, 119
6258, 571 -> 463, 7703, 3566489
```

Comment: Must we be able to accept input in any order or can we require a specific order?

Comment: @Shaggy you have to specify how you take input but other than that, its up to you

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>8</s> 7 bytes

```
<P<Ñʒ2›
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYKlpSVpuharbQJsDk88NcnoUcOuJcVJycVQ8QXLow2NdQwNYyFcAA) or [try all testcases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1weqySnslBV07BSX7yqWlJWm6FqttAmwOTzw1yehRw64lxUnJxYtqdSAyC27qRUcb65jE6kSb6lgASSNLHUsQZQYWMzTWMTQE0mZGphY6puaGsbEQbQA).

-1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

Lists the divisors of \$xy-x-y\$ greater than \$2\$.

Comment: If you take the input as a pair, the `*α¹-` can be `<P<` for -1 byte. (And the `ʒ2›` has some equal-bytes alternatives, like `¦2K`, `2LK` or `ć·K`, but I haven't found anything shorter.)

Answer (score 5):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
(ε*(─2╒-
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/1/j3FYtjUdTGoweTZ2k@/9/tLGOSSxXtKmOBZA0stSxBFFmYDFDYx1DQyBtZmRqoWNqbhgLAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
(        # Decrease both values in the (implicit) input-pair: [x-1,y-1]
 ε*      # Multiply them together: (x-1)*(y-1)
   (     # Decrease that by 1 as well: (x-1)*(y-1)-1
    ─    # Get all divisors
     2╒  # Push [1,2]
       - # Remove those values from the divisors-list
         # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 bytes

```
×__Fæ2>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWKw9Pj493O7zMyG5JcVJyMVR0wWJTLgsIEwA)

Based on Command Master’s idea, implemented a bit differently

```
×        # Multiply.          X * Y
 _       # Swapped subtract.  X * Y - X
  _      # Swapped subtract.  X * Y - X - Y
   F     # Factors.
    æ    # Filter by:
     2>  #   Greater than 2?
```

I chose Thunno 2 because of that swapped subtraction operator. It's the only stack golflang which has swapped versions of arithmetic operations, as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku (Perl 6) (rakudo)](https://raku.org), 41 bytes

```perl
{[3..($^x*$^y)].grep: 0==($x+$y-$x*$y)%*}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kKDG7dMHy3EoFlTQF26WlJWm6Fjc1q6ON9PQ0VOIqtFTiKjVj9dKLUgusFAxsbTVUKrRVKnVVgBKVmqpatVANMcWJIAM0jHUUTDStuaA8Ux0FCwTPyFJHwRKJa4ai1hCo1dAQwTczMrXQUTA1BwpB7FiwAEIDAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 52 bytes

```python
lambda x,y:[i for i in range(3,x*y)if(x+y)%i==x*y%i]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY5NboMwEIXX8SlGkaLY1ImK-TEg0YukWVAF2pHAWOBIcI_uuskmvVNu0zGhC9vzPc17zz-_dnZfvbndGyjh_X51zSF7xG3VfVwqmORcnBCafgAENDBU5rPmkZyCWWDDp5dZ7LAsCXd4Xr3f2Nl-cDDOI_PGFk3tvcTH0V3QFGyDxkqoJ0uVXWX5f1sBp8AzGidhOo62Rce3civEWS45q7SHwxvshWCb_uooo-EBJRLagax8EUvKogYyEorn326PNpIQe3fCEgmZn0jJJSjNFD25V5SKmErXxUhL0DELaS0MvUAc-hPmLFVJJiHRix6ntKL1K91RkqZxlj9L_wA)

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/products.htm), <sup><s>22</s> <s>17</s></sup> 16 bytes

-5 bytes thanks to [@ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)
-1 bytes thanks to [@att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att)

```
(2↓2∪∘⍸0=⍳|⊢)×-+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8EqK7_E3NTigsTk1KWlJWm6Fns1jB61TTZ61LHqUceMR707DGwf9W6uedS1SPPwdF3tJcVJycU3K9wetU141Ntn9Kir-VHf1OAgZyAZ4uEZzMUFZADljBXcFEygbFMg2wLKNrIEcixhHDMkVYYgLYaGUJ6ZkakFkG9qbshl5ZqXgubEBQsgNAA)

```
(2↓2∪∘⍸0=⍳|⊢)×-+­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
(2↓2∪∘⍸0=⍳|⊢)     ⍝ ‎⁡monadic function to get factors greater than 2:
           ⊢      ⍝ ‎⁢  arg
          |       ⍝ ‎⁣      mod
         ⍳        ⍝ ‎⁤          each number in range [1;arg]
       0=         ⍝ ‎⁢⁡  boolean vector, marking where result is 0
      ⍸           ⍝ ‎⁢⁢  ‎⁢⁢get indices of 1s
   2∪             ⍝ ‎⁢⁣  prepend 2 if not in array
 2↓               ⍝ ‎⁢⁤  drop first two elements (i.e. 1 and 2)
             ×-+  ⍝ ‎⁣⁡pass (⍺ × ⍵) - (⍺ + ⍵) to the function
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [`{2+⍸2↓0=⍵|⍨⍳⍵}×-+`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8EqK7_E3NTigsTk1KWlJWm6FvuqjbQf9e4wetQ22cD2Ue_Wmke9Kx71bgayag9P19VeUpyUXHyzwu1R24RHvX1Gj7qaH_VNDQ5yBpIhHp7BXFxABlDOWMFNwQTKNgWyLaBsI0sgxxLGMUNSZQjSYmgI5ZkZmVoA-abmhlxWrnkpaG5csABCAwA) saves a bit

Comment: another -1 with [`(2↓2∪∘⍸0=⍳|⊢)×-+`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qpTIxJz89PrEgZ8EqK7_E3NTigsTk1KWlJWm6Fns1jB61TTZ61LHqUceMR707DGwf9W6uedS1SPPwdF1tiJqbFW6P2iY86u0zetTV_KhvanCQM5AM8fAM5uICMoByxgpuCiZQtimQbQFlG1kCOZYwjhmSKkOQFkNDKM_MyNQCyDc1N-Sycs1LQXPjggUQGgA)

Answer (score 3):

## Google Sheets, 58 bytes

```
=let(p,A1*B1,s,sequence(1,p,3),filter(s,0=mod(p-A1-B1,s)))
```

Put \$x\$ in cell `A1`, \$y\$ in cell `B1` and the formula in cell `C1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 8 bytes

```
ᵋ*+-Ď~2>
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fqsfbu3W0tY90ldnZLekOCm5GCq-4KaCsYIJl6mCBZeRpYIll5EZkGdorGBoyGVmZGqhYGpuCFEIAA)

```
ᵋ*+-Ď~2>
ᵋ*          x * y
  +         x + y
   -        minus
    Ď       divisors
     ~      choose an element from the list
      2>    check if it is greater than 2
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 56 bytes

```c
i;f(x,y){for(i=x*y;--i>2;)(x*y-x-y)%i?:printf("%d ",i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJ/b4IwEP3fT3EhWQLaZlp@qd3cH4ufYprFYHF1W12UZGWGrz52UMDKNhKa4967947rJXSXJGUpeepqknvn9HB05b0e5pxSuWDcczGmmubejXyYfxylylLXudmCQ6THi3KACXjfSOV6cB4APlVC6A@RZGL7PH5awz2cw4Jf5ycm7xOYEWBxH2YGZszvI35TGBOIgz4YGBCxSfVOZn1CaAhBhMZxPMbTD6MomLbETJwy3bUWYmtVexFq4WfEwqnFyxstAtP6L4LKEYviiSENO1tDvMyEWHOwYmbFvhUHVtwfpDLaKIMVeLI6wKnVV5Ec1CmD5GVzHOIpkldxNHxnpZdspWeP@IYOAfvbd5pqXAVwKzOptkJj2Zg34R2c5Jc4pG7bhge3bWrY5TiMRjW/3Yx2OyotM@kaXvMrNG/Q/Bd62T4CuIF0gUsImkDuXTjVGl8lzE2gZncbf5kqi6D@NV6pZcOZg2ObtpPao4zisOf2L1@3XvUsnijdry2B4g@r1qAYFOV3kr5tdqeSfv4A)

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 46 bytes

```javascript
x=>y=>{for(m=x*y,q=m-x-y;--m>2;)q%m||print(m)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc3RCsIgFMbx@z3FuQk0lKFuORn6LiMQFlibjaG0nt3MILw4N/8ffOc27dPz6udlo/uQrE5Bm6jNyz48cjqcI1m1o4HGkVJn@IjXkzuOxc/3DTn8ThaBwAg6DG0LffMD3OTc5zyULAgoAlxWylVWVZRzUcPlvyYkAdlVxvInxoplYt9jKn0A)

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```javascript
(x,m=2)=>g=y=>++m<x*y?((x*y-x-y)%m?"":m+" ")+g(y):""
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc7RCoMgFIDh@z3FQRjotIVaa8asZ4lWspE51hj59C7pZnhxzs3/cTjP7tst/fvx@mSzuw9h1AGvzGpBdGO01w2l9raefIvxtrM18@RoW4RqSxEgQg32pEYo9G5e3DScJ2fwiEESDFAQAnkO5SGJZYzXPUoGioGoEiNUNGo3Qsg0X/7uy4pBVSSCxw8438UGeByuwg8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>38</s> 35 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844).*

```hs
x#y=[m|m<-[3..x*y],1>mod(x*y-x-y)m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY5LCoMwGIT3nmLATVL@CNHGKlRv0BOkWQQqVGqsVBcJ9O6plG7SWQ0fzONu18cwTTH6PHTavd1Z6Koo/CEYkr173thuhReBOxO3Yd1WdNDQFeFoMvxE0IrQJKBsCW1K6v@Q3GukTFBdqoagTtLAZJmz47wPOrtcwJbXOG8owK7aE4KB6OGRI3CO77X4AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 80 bytes

```go
func(x,y int)(M[]int){for m:=3;m<x*y;m++{if(x*y-x-y)%m<1{M=append(M,m)}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVFLasMwEKVbnWJqMMiNEup_fioUmmVKaLNrSzGOFUxjx7XlYCN8gh6hm1DoodLTVJaTkIU0mvfefDTz_bPe7g9mFoQfwTqCJIhTFCfZNucDjSVcOzvFJg6jQkNoF-TA6G_JWX94WLAyDXFFaohTbuD5y1trBdvmkIypPUmm1U09SXo9ETMsn_2qXxt6MjXFnAZZFqUrPCeJ0TQoj3iZp02X9-_qi9dZBEsoeF6GHMSxxASiKgNVpVGd8KjgBVAJLQUSNgGHdLRwm4Yg4RIYnhDJjghYviKskfI6xrLsDvQuEtg-Ad9RuClDTfNESNxsjzlSpGe5soTrn3nHk3Lfv5W37XqeM1S6BqF2WGrE2ACBFrkUb1KsUUqfl_dPS2k1A7WzeyccxhTyIJU76b4oUBAqkGE-qAjwQW2gmMH17LMMNliSLSanI1ODSs2wpq8I6Cugd6DvAOs74zXVWlkXT-AyqpEdXrY0e3zoGjruZL_v7D8)

Uses the factors of \$xy-x-y \gt 2\$ method.

## [Go](https://go.dev), 81 bytes

```go
func(x,y int)(M[]int){for m:=3;m<x*y;m++{if(x+y)%m==x*y%m{M=append(M,m)}}
return}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVHdSsMwGMXbPMVnoZC6OGy7tvsxguAuJ_7sTkVK14zi0tU2HS2hT-AjeDMEH2o-jWm6jV0kH9855_vJyffPcr3d2VkYfYTLGHiYpCjh2ToXfYNxYRyTYpVEcWEgtAlzYPS3FOxyuHtkZRrhitSQpMLCs5e3Nkq2zoGPqTvh19VFPeG9nkwYrnq1ZXJKFWRyOaNhlsXpAs8It5oG5bEo87TpGv-dfYk6i2EOhcjLSIDcz5hAXGWgxzR6FREXogCqoLlE0iUwIB0tvaYhSHoEhgdEsSMCTqAJZ6SzjnEctwP9kwZuQCAYaNxWpbZ9IBRut8ceadJ3PDXCC478wFfyILhSt-v5_mCodQ1CrVvaY2yBRA-5Eq9SbFBKn-e3T3MVDQu15r0TAWMKeZiqT-meKFEYaZBh0a8IiH5toYTB-fSzDFdYkS2m3FGtQbdm2DAXBMwF0BswN4DNjfWaGq2sqydwWtWoDU9Xmt7fdQvt_2S77eI_)

Formula as verbatim, \$xy \equiv x+y  \pmod m\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 19 bytes

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮＩΦ…³Πυ¬﹪⁻ΠυΣυι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYoxDsIwDEX3nsKjLYUhdOyIhMTQKoIThFBopDRBjs31QyQG/vbe@2HzHIpPrT0LAx4JnNYN1cAlv1UW3e8rI9E0OI5Z8OSr4Dkm6fbq82vF0YDj8tAgqEQGliI4d04F55i14r8auOn@e0Xqm1qz42BtO3zSFw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮ
```

Input `x` and `y` and push them to the predefined empty list.

```
ＩΦ…³Πυ¬﹪⁻ΠυΣυι
```

Output all numbers between `3` and the product of the list that are factors of the difference between the product and the sum.

21 bytes for a faster version that can handle the last test case in a more reasonable amount of time:

```
Ｆ²⊞υＮＩ⁺³⌕Ａ﹪⁻ΠυΣυ…³Πυ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYtNCsIwEIX3PUWWE4iglarQVRGELipBTxDTagPTRCaZXj@mKzfv53s8OxuywWDO70ACaik0xxlYid5/Od15eU0EUraVJucTXE1MoJEjHJW4OT92iDCEkTHA4HzhmkqzCVgq8eSleAkP4z/TdvmvG94XlW3Op7q5VM35kHcr/gA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Vectorises the remainder check and then finds the positions of the zero remainders.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 32 bytes

```r
\(x,y,a=x*y-x-y)which(!a%%3:a)+2
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY5NCsIwEIX3nmJECqlOwPwnQj2JmyCEupWKyd5buImCh_I2TklxMX_few_m-brWdxo-tylx_4UTy1gwDnlbeOalv4-X88jWsevUIfY7ufgeiSkE3W-AH8GsEjMIvl3EA4J0BCUtoVEp1QzsP6QcgtPEBAWEaJCYmEsEEqw0HsG4RdOWjM7tqStjrfah_VJrmz8)

Port of [Command Master's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269713/55372).

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 35 bytes

```r
\(x,y,M=3:(p=x*y))M[p%%M==(x+y)%%M]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY5NCgIxDIX3niIwDLSaAfvfCvUGPYG67XoQhXbvLdxUwUN5GzN0cJHk5Xt5kOfr2t45fu63PPnvcGYFK6aoDmyOZVs5T6d5HFOMrOwqJ3VZTx-ZKQTNB5iOYDaZGQTfN-IBQTqCkkToVEq1APsPKYfgNDFBASE6JCaWEoEMK41HMG71tKVD5_bUlbFW-9B_aa3PHw)

Straightforward approach.

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org) <sup>[SBCS](https://tinyurl.com/Uiua-SBCS-Jan-14)</sup>, <s>19</s> 15 bytes

```
▽=⊃∩◿∘,:↘3⇡.⊃×+
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4pa9PeKKg-KIqeKXv-KImCw64oaYM-KHoS7iioPDlysKCmYgMyA0CmYgNSA4CmYgMjkgOQpmIDI2IDQKZiAxMyAxMQpmIDYyNTggNTcxCg==)

-4 bytes thanks to Tbw

Comment: 15 bytes https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__ZiDihpAg4pa9PTDil78sOuKGmDIrMeKHoS4tOi06w5csLApmIOKGkCDilr094oqD4oip4pe_4oiYLDrihpgz4oehLuKKg8OXKwpmIDMgNApmIDUgOApmIDI5IDkKZiAyNiA0CmYgMTMgMTEKZiA2MjU4IDU3MQo=

Comment: @Tbw Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Divisors[##-##]/. 1|2->Set@$&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73yWzLLM4v6g4WllZV1k5Vl9PwbDGSNcuOLXEQUXtf0BRZl5JtLKuXZqDg3KsWl1wcmJeXTVXtbGOSa0OV7WpjgWIMrLUsQTTZhBhQ2MdQ0MQw8zI1ELH1Nywlqv2PwA)

Input `[x, y]`. `##-##` is not zero - it computes the sum minus the product of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 bytes

```
’P’ÆD>Ƈ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Rw8wAID7c5mJ3rN3o////0YbGOgqGhrEA)

Port of [Command Master’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269713/106959).

-1 byte and a bugfix thanks to [@Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78410/bubbler)

### Explanation:

```
’P’ÆD>Ƈ2­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
’         # ‎⁡Decrement both values in the list: [x - 1, y - 1]
 P        # ‎⁢Product of the list: (x - 1) * (y - 1)
  ’       # ‎⁣Decrement again: ((x - 1) * (y - 1)) - 1
   ÆD     # ‎⁤Get the divisors
      Ƈ   # ‎⁢⁡Keep items that satisfy the condition below
     > 2  # ‎⁢⁢Greater than 2
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: `ÆḌ` should be `ÆD` I think? Also `>2$Ƈ­⁡​‎‎` can be `>Ƈ2­⁡​‎‎`.

Comment: @Bubbler fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-BASIC, 25 bytes

```
For(M,3,prod(Ans)-1
If not(fPart(M⁻¹min(ΔList(Ans
Disp M
End
```

Takes input in `Ans` as a list of two integers. Add a `)` to the end of the first line to make it faster.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 50 bytes

```
.+
$*
1(?=1+¶1(1+))
$1
M!&`(111+)\b(?<=^11\1+)
%`1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcgxCoMwGAbQ/TtFhKT8miB8akWh4uLq5BpKFBxcOpSezQN4sZiO73333/FZo5El@MnG0kIXoIwD7XVSaPMcmpizRxAy0W8yvoY36RNgAiNh5lBC4zpj7VSDp1Mdqt6pHlX7D6Ymbw) Link is to test suite for faster test cases that splits input on non-digits and spaces the outputs apart. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
1(?=1+¶1(1+))
$1
```

Calculate `1+(x-1)(y-1)`, as that's golfier than trying to subtract `x` or `y` afterwards.

```
M!&`(111+)\b(?<=^11\1+)
```

Subtract `2` and find all factors that are greater than `2`.

```
%`1
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 45 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)3..($p=$a*$b)|?{!(($a+$b-$p)%$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/dToNAEIWv2acYcWpAl0ZYYMsFEW301sZeGtMsuE1jaEB@ognl2XEQqclsMuecOV@yZfGlq/qg89zJikoPuI@7oVSVOlqoOKa2WC4tLGNU1yROd92FRcENpg6W9gJ3dj/0jCUWA@CJJTj4HMzAtCcdcFiRFhCBJ2fTizjQmJ4nzlY4FYUE6c@mSzTXJVeCS@NGv8ElJaEXEDaQY@iHAqS8FSCCMPRX45ENJ3gqqkeVHZzn9ENnDXTMoO8ApvT0d0mWfocYcEd@pes2b0hd4R5Q0REzXjfbdVs3xXHqv0FCBGPbZpmuazo1/1omOPrzH0k39yNW0fIwLoQyXmb@ucSMnvVs@AE)

Saved two bytes using [rajashekar](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/104396/rajashekar)'s method, upvote [their answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/269741/97729)!